# GIMP Commands History per Layer in the XCF?

Tags: gimp, text, layers

There is a feature so useful in a graphics editor that I cannot believe it cannot be found in GIMP. Maybe it's buried in some menus?

Have a GIMP `.xcf` file with a few layers that was created some time ago. One of these layers was initially a text layer, but the text image itself has been processed at the time. And when I click on it (after the text layer itself has been selected), I get

[image]

I want to change the text and apply the *same filters* to the new text as the ones that were applied to the initial text at the time.

Is there a way to list the commands / filters that were applied to a layer *before* it was saved as a `.xcf`? In other terms, does GIMP save the filters applied to a layer in the `xcf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, when you save an XCF, the undo stack isn't saved with it. Note that the undo stack is anyway the state of layers, not how you obtained it.

What you really want is non destructive editing (so you could edit the text, and whatever processing downstream would automatically be repeated), which is in the works for Gimp V3.

Comment: Ok thanks, any idea when V3 is to be released?

Comment: @RingØ Don't hold your breath :)